# SharePoint 2013 Workflow - building dictionaries based off conditions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library, managed-metadata

I have been searching everywhere to try and get an answer for my specific problem within SharePoint Designer, perhaps my grammar and terminology is not correct.

I am currently in the process of creating a site for two teams, these two teams fall under the same term set (taxonomy) for example term1, I have then created another term set that contains two terms (sub groups under term1 but not within term1), team one and team two.  I needed to do this due to the site potentially branching out and other teams being added to the site except under different term sets.  I have then created a content type that contains two managed metadata columns one for term1 and the other for team one and team two.

Ok, what I am trying to do is when either of these teams upload a document to the same document library a workflow will kick in and set the two managed metadata columns depending on what the file name contains.  Initially the first managed metadata column will be based on term1, but the other column will be based on team one or team two.

I have managed to create a 2013 workflow using the following resource https://mariagraziamerlo.com/2016/01/04/how-to-update-a-managed-metadata-field-using-a-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/

I managed to get the workflow to set the columns based on what the file name contains but I am now trying to make the workflow to be a bit more dynamic by comparing the current file name with the value on another list and then build the other dictionaries depending on what the file name and lookup list value match on.  For some reason this is not working.

Here is an image of my workflow if that helps at all.  I really appreciate the help and would be more than happy to provide further context.

[image: My Workflow]

Comment: Apologies, this is for SharePoint Online.